# Should the review options page list items by required reputation?

Tags: discussion

It currently seems to be listed arbitrarily(maybe by overall SE setup or something?).

It seems odd that the second and fourth item require 3k, but the third and fifth item require 2k.

Answer (score 4):

They are listed in order of the number of items which require review.

Comment: Then when all are equal (as 0 currently), should they not be listed by required reputation?